# how to set more than one condition in Doctrine ManyToMany

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

how to set more than one condition in doctrine ManyToMany ..

**model**

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="users",inversedBy="friends",cascade={"ALL"})
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="friends",
 *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="friend_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
 *      )
 */
private $groupsa;

public function getusersre() {
    return $this->groupsa;
}
```

**output**

```
    SELECT 
  t0.id AS id_1, 
  t0.email AS email_2, 
  t0.username AS username_3, 
  t0.password AS password_4, 
  t0.first_name AS first_name_5, 
  t0.last_name AS last_name_6, 
  t0.location AS location_7, 
  t0.remember_token AS remember_token_8, 
  t0.created_at AS created_at_9, 
  t0.updated_at AS updated_at_10 
FROM 
  users t0 
  INNER JOIN friends ON t0.id = friends.user_id 
WHERE 
  friends.friend_id = ?
```

i want that it be like this

```
 WHERE 
  friends.friend_id = ?
or friends.xxxx_id = ?
```

wait for a reponse , thanks for all ....

Comment: [custom repository class](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#custom-repository-classes), then [query builder](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html)

Comment: What does `friends.xxxx_id` mean? Any particular field? It could help if you post both `Users` and `Friends` entities.

Comment: Show us the querybuilder or DQL code you have so far please.

Comment: Looking also at your previous questions I think you should read [how do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

You can do as @SergioIvanuzzo suggests, but if you want to do this inside your entity you can also use the doctrine `Doctrine\Common\Collections\Criteria` class for this. You can read all about it in the documentation chapter **[8.8. Filtering Collections](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/working-with-associations.html#filtering-collections)**.

```
public function getFriends(){
    $id = 1; // ...the id you want to use for filtering
    $criteria = Criteria::create()
        ->where(Criteria::expr()->eq("xxxx_id", $id));

    return $this->friends->matching($criteria);
}
```

Comment: @hz4web Did it work out with using Criteria? Was this what you were looking for?